# Getting error in Informatica SQL30081N in a Source qualifier after fetching 11424 rows

Tags: db2, informatica

We are getting below error in an Informatica workflow. The same is running seamlessly in pilot environment, issue is in production.

After 11424 rows are selected this error is thrown from z/Os DB2.
This source qualifier query if run separately fetches 2.6 million rows.
The buffer is set to Auto in the Informatica session properties.

```
SQL Error [
[IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. 
Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  
Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  
Location where the error was detected: "<server-ip 11:22:22:22 format>".  
Communication function detecting the error: "send".  
Protocol specific error code(s): "32", "*", "0".  
SQLSTATE=08001
sqlstate = 40003 

Database driver  error...
Function name  Fetch
Native error  code = -30081
```

This is expected to be run successfully as we have not made any changes to this workflow. This started failing a few weeks back.

I did some reading on this error and what I could find said this is due to connection blocked by DB2 firewall. If this is the case why only one select statement is failing while other source qualifiers are running successfully?

Comment: EDIT your question to add missing information (1) what is in the Db2-server diagnostics file for seconds leading up to the timestamp of the error (2) what is the Db2-server operating-system (z/os, i-series, linux/unix/windows)  .  Your question is not about programming, but about **troubleshooting**, and only your site has the diagnostic data.

Comment: I do agree that this is more of a trouble shooting. My idea was to get some insights from someone who might have already faced a similar issue and could give me some pointers on how to get around this issue.

Comment: Please also include information whether rows were fetched on by-one or e.g. there could have been a long pause in fetches. If the latter, then we shall look also into different TCP/IP parameters.

Comment: @PeterGerald 
3 possible causes:
- TCP/IP timeout
- WLM threshold that forces the connection automatically 
- some Db2 problem (there was a recent APAR with  Db2 MPP and columnar tables that could cause it)
this is why we do need more details about the database.

Comment: @kkuduk DB2 Server is running z/os . I have added more information to the query.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Db2 manual below, it it typically outside the Db2 software:

**Protocol-specific error codes for the SQL30081N message**
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.doc/doc/r0052008.html

---

The cause of the SQL30081N message is typically outside the Db2 software and actual error codes are protocol-specific.

---

And here is a documented link for error number **32** :

**TCP/IP errors**
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.doc/doc/r0058740.html

```
Table 1. UNIX TCP/IP error numbers

errnos  AIX error number    Linux error number  Description

   :

EPIPE   32  32  Broken pipe.
```

So generally speaking, it is suggested to check TCP/IP level.

Hope this helps.

Comment: We tried to 
1. increase the connection retries in the connection object in Informatica
2. Increase the buffer size
3. Adding index to a table which is used in the lookup, as we suspect probably this error is due to the lookup taking too much time as the number of records is 3 times compared to that in the source qualifier in which the error is thrown. 
Will keep you posted. Thanks for the inputs.